# PyQtGraph custom graphics item causes white square to appear at origin

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have a `PyQtGraph` custom data item and it's causing a white square to appear at the origin that is not in the data. The white square is only visible when your zoomed in a little.

The custom graphics item:

```
class ParticalRendererItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self,data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
        self.generatePicture()
    
    def generatePicture(self):
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        for partical in self.data:
            prodPos = QtCore.QPoint(partical.xProd,partical.yProd)
            momentumPos = QtCore.QPoint(partical.px,partical.py)
            p.drawLine(prodPos,momentumPos)
        p.end()
    def paint(self,p,*args):
        p.drawPicture(0,0,self.picture)
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())
```

the data is a list of a class `partical` that has all those attributes.

Here is the graph:
[image: The White Square]